# Convert a 12 hour format to 24 hour format in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

there  are date values in the below format,in one of the sql server 2000 tables

```
10/1/2013 10:39:14 PM
10/1/2013 6:39:04  PM
10/1/2013 8:19:31  AM
10/1/2013 3:35:40  AM
```

how to convert the above format data values into a 24hour date format,as shown below

```
10/1/2013 10:39
10/1/2013 18:39
10/1/2013 8:19
10/1/2013 3:35
```

Comment: Do you store your dates as varchar? or date? Can you show table schema?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

First convert `varchar` date to `datetime` and then you can manipulate it in the way you want as:

```
-- CONVERT TO DATETIME TO GET 24HR FORMAT
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '10/1/2013 6:39:04  PM', 0)  
-- Concatenate in required format
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, '10/1/2013 6:39:04  PM', 0), 101) 
+ ' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CONVERT(DATETIME, '10/1/2013 6:39:04  PM', 0), 108)
```

Answer (score 23):

In SQL Server 2012, we can use Format function to have suitable date time format. Use capital letter 'HH:mm:ss' for 24 hour date time format.

Example -

**Query (24 hour format):**

```
Select Format(cast('2016-03-03 23:59:59' as datetime),'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss','en-us'). ('HH:mm:ss' in Capital letters)
```

**Result**

```
03-Mar-2016 23:59:59
```

**Query (12 hour format):**

```
Select Format(cast('2016-03-03 23:59:59' as datetime),'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss','en-us'). ('hh:mm:ss' in Capital letters)
```

**Result**

```
03-Mar-2016 11:59:59
```

Comment: This query returns an error, it says "Common language runtime (CLR) execution is not supported under lightweight pooling. Disable one of two options: "clr enabled" or "lightweight pooling"." Is there any oher way in converting the time in a 12 hour format other than format function?

Answer (score 3):

```
Declare @s DateTime = '2012-12-26 11:00:00.000 PM'
select stuff(convert(varchar(19), @s, 126),11,1,' ')
```

Comment: i did this in sql-server 2012

Comment: there's an implicit conversion in the first line. If OP stores dates as strings, it's better to use varchar variable in your example

Comment: thank you..but i d o not think i can store a varchar value in date time variable

Comment: Declare @s DateTime = '2012-12-26 11:00:00.000 PM'
is it correct?

Comment: that is true it would work sql 2005 and above..but my db is sql 2000

Comment: @user1254579 you cannot store varchar value in datetime variable. There's an implicit conversion in the assingment

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
DECLARE @MyDateTime; 
SET @MyDateTime = '2016-03-03 23:59:59'
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,@MyDateTime,108),'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss','en-us')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @Hour_Part AS VARCHAR(50)
declare @Min_Part AS VARCHAR(50)
declare @Sec_Part AS VARCHAR(50)
declare @PMORAM AS VARCHAR(5)
SELECT @Hour_Part = DATEPART(HOUR,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108))
SELECT @PMORAM =  RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 9), 2) 
IF @Hour_Part = 12 AND @PMORAM = 'AM'
BEGIN
SET @Hour_Part = '00'
select @Min_Part = DATEPART(MINUTE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108))
select @Sec_Part = DATEPART(SECOND,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108))
select @Hour_Part + ':' + @Min_Part + ':' + @Sec_Part AS DateTime24
END
ELSE IF @Hour_Part > 0 AND @Hour_Part < 12 AND @PMORAM = 'PM'
BEGIN
SET @Hour_Part = @Hour_Part + 12
select @Min_Part = DATEPART(MINUTE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108))
select @Sec_Part = DATEPART(SECOND,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108))
select @Hour_Part + ':' + @Min_Part + ':' + @Sec_Part AS DateTime24
END
ELSE
BEGIN
select @Min_Part = DATEPART(MINUTE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108))
select @Sec_Part = DATEPART(SECOND,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108))
select @Hour_Part + ':' + @Min_Part + ':' + @Sec_Part AS DateTime24
END
```