# RODBC SQL Query missing AM/PM time information

Tags: sql, r, datetime, rodbc

I use `RODBC` to read some fields from MS Dynamics CRM database.

```
ch <- odbcConnect(dsn.name, believeNRows=FALSE, rows_at_time=1)
results <- sqlQuery(ch, "SELECT ActualStart, ActualEnd, CreatedOn FROM Appointment LIMIT 1000", as.is=c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

where all the fields are date-time fields.

My problem is, all the time info seem to be missing the AM or PM information.

```
> head(results)
          ActualStart           ActualEnd           CreatedOn
1 2010-10-30 02:10:57 2010-10-31 11:25:19 2010-10-31 11:25:18
2 2010-11-02 02:09:26 2010-11-02 02:21:59 2010-11-02 02:21:58
3 2010-11-02 02:13:27 2010-11-02 02:22:01 2010-11-02 02:22:00
4 2010-11-02 02:17:49 2010-11-02 02:22:13 2010-11-02 02:22:01
5 2010-11-02 02:19:59 2010-11-02 02:22:14 2010-11-02 02:22:14
6                <NA> 2011-07-18 06:22:50 2011-07-07 06:42:49
```

And it's not a military-style 24-hour time either.

```
> require(lubridate)
> table(hour(results$ActualStart))

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
  7   9  11  75 206 226  61  34 200  99  51   6  

> table(substr(results$CreatedOn, 12, 13))

 01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12 
  7   8  11  75 207 233  65  34 204  99  52   5
```

And as you can see in the above, tweaking to `as.is` to force reading as character didn't help. I have verified source elsewhere that there are at least a few data where the numbers are in pm while the majority are in am.

Any suggestions on how can I retrieve the am / pm info ?

Comment: Why not convert the 12 hour format to 24 hour character string within SQL statement? What SQL are you using? For example: [Convert a 12 hour format to 24 hour format in sql 2000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563261/convert-a-12-hour-format-to-24-hour-format-in-sql-2000)

Comment: MS Dynamics CRM database uses MS SQL, so this question is kind of a duplicate to mentioned link above.

Comment: The dates are `datetime` so I assume in the link you gave, I will drop the conversion from `varchar`.

I'm calling the SQL statement from within R using RODBC package. when I pass

 `results <- sqlQuery(ch, "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CreatedOn, 108) FROM Appointment LIMIT 100")`

I got the following error

`[1] "HY000 -1 Unknown function: CONVERT"

[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CreatedOn, 108) FROM Appointment LIMIT 100'"`