# SQL Sort Date and Time ASC

Tags: sql, date, datetime

I've been working on a scheduling application with has two fields: Date and time.

User picks date from a calendar and User selects time by drop downs
Data types are: datetime and time (7)

I am trying to list the dates and times ASC.

example:
What I would like to achieve.

```
9/1/2016  8:05 AM
9/1/2016  9:00 AM
9/1/2016  10:30 AM
9/1/2016  11:00 AM
9/1/2016  2:00 PM
```

What I am receiving.

```
9/1/2016  2:00 PM 
9/1/2016  8:05 AM
9/1/2016  9:00 AM
9/1/2016  10:30 AM
9/1/2016  11:00 AM
```

I've tried sorting by two columns of date, time ASC with no success.

What would be a good way to be able to list these in the appropriate order?

Comment: You can use spacebar to achieve <br> effect too.Also please tag the relevant RDBMS you are using like sqlserver/oracle/..

Comment: You need it in ascending order or descending order?

Comment: Is this happening in a client application, did it convert time to string? is this in a query?

Comment: Its needing to be in ASC order to list date and time earliest to latest.

Comment: The date is datetime and the time is Time(7).  if I have 9:00 am and 2:00 PM in a list, 2:00 will list first and basically ignoring am/pm

Comment: "*The date is datetime*" - why do you have a datetime **and** a time column? Why don't you use the time in the datetime column?

Comment: Because horse, the application calls for separate dates and times. I'm just building what the specs say.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- CONVERT TO DATETIME TO GET 24HR FORMAT

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '9/1/2016 8:05 AM', 0)  

-- Concatenate in required format

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, '9/1/2016 8:05 AM', 0), 101) 
+ ' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CONVERT(DATETIME, '9/1/2016 8:05 AM', 0), 108)
```

Then try to order by ASC or DESC as required.

[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563261/convert-a-12-hour-format-to-24-hour-format-in-sql-2000)

Comment: Converting to 24 hour string format may not be desired by OP and if you want to order by date it isn't necessary if the data type is a date/datetime simply ASC or DESC will do the same thing without conversion.  Also if you are going to post an exact answer from another post you should just mark the question as duplicate and comment it.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared an example to satisfy your requirement,
Please check and let me know if any changes required

```
declare @tbl as table 
(
dt datetime
,tm time(7)
)

insert into @tbl
select '2001-02-01','12:00:00'

insert into @tbl
select '2001-01-02','13:00:00'

insert into @tbl
select '2001-01-01','15:00:00'


select convert(varchar(10),dt,101)+' '+ right(convert(varchar(25),tm,100),7) from @tbl
order by dt,tm
```

Comment: how do you know T.J. is using SQL Server?

Comment: tagged "sql, date, datetime". but not sure that why i said i have created an example.

Comment: The tag `sql` refers to the query language SQL. The tag `sql-server` refers to the DBMS product from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query ,if you are using SQL Server.

```
SELECT *
FROM  Yourtable
ORDER BY [date],cast([Time] as time(7))
```

Comment: updated.. by the way,question is raised by T.J (not muthu..)