# Custom Datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, datetime-format

I want to insert a datetime in custom format in SQL Server 2017 but could not figure out how

```
INSERT INTO TIMEZONE_CONVERSION (TZ_ID, OFFSET_TO_UTC, START_TIME, END_TIME)
VALUES (3, 60, 
        CONVERT(DATETIME, '25-10-2015 03:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
        CONVERT(DATETIME, '27-03-2016 02:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
        'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

When I execute it this error occurs:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 3 of convert function.

I have searched here in Stackoverflow but none of the solutions worked for me. Maybe you will need the to know the DDL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [TIMEZONE_CONVERSION] 
(
    [TZC_ID] [NUMERIC](18, 0) IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TZ_ID] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NOT NULL, 
    [OFFSET_TO_UTC] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NOT NULL, 
    [START_TIME] [DATETIME] NOT NULL, 
    [END_TIME] [DATETIME] NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT [TZ_CONV_PK] PRIMARY KEY ([TZC_ID])
)
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear and so is the documentation of the CONVERT function.   What makes you think you can use `DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` for the third argument?   Are you following some tutorial somewhere, or just wishfully thinking the documentation doesn't apply to you?

Comment: `datetime` has no format at all. It's a binary value. In any case, the error complains about an invalid call, not an invalid format.

Comment: You can avoid all conversion problems by *not* using localized strings. Either use parameterized queries with `datetime`-typed parameters or used the unambiguous ISO8601  format. There are a *lot* of duplicate questions that show how to do that

Comment: convert(varchar(19), '25-10-2015 03:00:00',20)

Comment: You can also look at this answer which have 5 votes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563261/convert-a-12-hour-format-to-24-hour-format-in-sql-server

Comment: @TabAlleman Isnt my link rather the duplicate than the one which is marked as dublicate. He trys to convert it to 24 HOURS datetime

Comment: @Thomas, no because this poster is trying to INSERT data to a datetime column in a certain format.   The answer in the question I flagged explains that you cannot format the data in a datetime column, you can only format it when converting to a string in a SELECT query.   If the poster were doing a SELECT rather than an INSERT, I would agree with you.

Comment: @TabAlleman Ahh - Well spotted :)