# Convert datetime from 12 hour format to 24 hour format

Tags: sql-server

Given the following data:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| Started                  | Ended                    |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| 2020-06-08 01:09:46.000  | 2020-06-08 01:29:51.000  |
| 2020-06-09 12:55:40.000  | 2020-06-09 01:28:33.000  |
| 2020-06-10 12:59:30.000  | 2020-06-10 01:24:37.000  |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I need to convert these to 24 hour format. My end goal is to get the time difference in minutes between these two values, but the fact that it's 12 hour format is hindering my efforts.

Unfortunately, they are valid `datetime` values so running `CONVERT` or `CAST` commands on the values don't do anything.

So how do I get these values into 24 hour format?

I've had a look at the answers at [Convert a 12 hour format to 24 hour format in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563261/convert-a-12-hour-format-to-24-hour-format-in-sql-server)

Still at a loss.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One potential issue with this question is how do you differentiate AM or PM? You would have to make assumptions that 1 means PM, 6 means AM, etc. Do you have a concrete way, perhaps through another table, to verify whether these times are in AM or PM?

Comment: @BrentGeorge business logic; highly unlikely any hour lower than 8 (being 8AM) is morning so I'm safe to assume that 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 are PM hours. These are my own timesheets based on Toggl that I'm working with and I don't work past 8 at night

Comment: First, [DateTime has no format](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/), only it's string representation do. Second, unless the string representation includes `AM` or `PM` - how can you tell if it's `01:09` or `13:09`?

Comment: If all are assumed to PM, just add 12 hours  dateadd(HOUR,12,yourDT)

Comment: Hi Ortund, why not just use datediff like this, `datediff(minute, started  , ended ) `? This would achieve the minute difference you need, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement within an update clause to check against your business logic (1:00-7:00 are PM times).

A DATEPART function checks the hour part of your datetime object. If the hour is less than 8 (i.e. 1-7), then use a DATEADD function to add 12 hours to your date. Below is the script and the sample table I used.

Script

```
UPDATE
  [MySchema].[TestDates]
SET 
  DateIn24Hr = CASE WHEN DATEPART("hh", DateInAMPM) < 8 THEN DATEADD(hour, 12, DateInAMPM) ELSE DateInAMPM END
```

TestDates before

```
    +--------------------------+--------------------------+
    | DateInAMPM               | DateIn24Hr               |
    +--------------------------+--------------------------+
    | 2020-06-08 01:09:46.000  | NULL                     |
    | 2020-06-09 06:12:46.000  | NULL                     |
    | 2020-06-10 09:12:46.000  | NULL                     |
    | 2020-06-11 12:12:46.000  | NULL                     |
    +--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

TestDates after

```
    +--------------------------+--------------------------+
    | DateInAMPM               | DateIn24Hr               |
    +--------------------------+--------------------------+
    | 2020-06-08 01:09:46.000  | 2020-06-08 13:09:46.000  |
    | 2020-06-09 06:12:46.000  | 2020-06-09 18:12:46.000  |
    | 2020-06-10 09:12:46.000  | 2020-06-10 09:12:46.000  |
    | 2020-06-11 12:12:46.000  | 2020-06-11 12:12:46.000  |
    +--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is no Need to Convert The Datetimes to Get The Minute Difference**

Leverage the DATEDIFF function to get the net minute difference between the two dates.

Using the modulus function, remove the minutes attributed to day difference.

With the example below, there is a 6 hour difference (6 hours * 60 min/hour) = 360 minute difference.

```
 --need some sample data
with smple AS ( SELECT
    getdate()                                                AS start_dt,
    dateadd(day, 1, dateadd(hour, 6, getdate()))             AS end_dt)
--end sample data
SELECT
    start_dt,
    end_dt,
    datediff(minute, start_dt, end_dt) %1440 as Min_Diff
FROM smple;
```

Result set:

[image]