# How to get 12 hour time from 24 hour string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of varchar type which stores time value as 24hr format like 08:20, 14:30 etc
I need the output as 12hr format like 8:20 AM, 2:30 PM respectively

[image]

What should be the query in SQL Server?

Comment: Maybe you can use this, only convert the other way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563261/convert-a-12-hour-format-to-24-hour-format-in-sql-server

Comment: `SELECT FORMAT(CAST('14:30' AS DATETIME), 't', 'en-US')` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#ShortTime

Comment: This is a job for your presentation layer really, not the SQL layer. Though why are you storing a *time* value as a `varchar`, and not a `time`? *That* is the real problem. What would stop something storing the value `'25:17'`, or `'12:97'`, or worse, just a nonsense value like `'asjdh'`?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @tm VARCHAR(20)= '13:40'
select FORMAT(CAST(@tm AS DATETIME), 't')
```

Comment: they want `h` rather than `hh`